# How do you rsync build files from Gitlab CI to another server

Tags: rsync, ssh-keys, gitlab-ci

It's unclear to me how to get my build files from the Gitlab CI (hosted on https://ci.gitlab.com) over to my personal server using rsync.

I have setup **1 test** and **1 deploy** job.

Under the *deploy tab* I have inputed the bash commands to:

1. Install rsync
2. Update packages
3. Finally, the rsync command to
   transfer files over SSH to my personal server.

When I enter the SSH credentials (with verbose flag on) for my private personal server, it would appear that the SSH key is the issue. In Gitlab, I have already established the deploy key (for hooks - tested this and it works).

Where do I locate the **public SSH key for the Gitlab deploy instance** so that I can install that key on my server?

Below is the exact script entered in Gitlab CI deploy job script pane:

```
# Run as root
(
set -e
set -u
set -x
apt-get update -y
apt-get -y install rsync
)
git clone https://github.com/bla/deployments.git $HOME/deploy/deployments
SVR_WEB1_WEBSERVER="000.11.22.333"
USER1="franklin"
GROUP1="team1"
FROM_DIR="/gitlab-ci-runner/tmp/builds/myrepo-1/"
DEST1="subdomains/gitlab/myrepo"
EXCLUSIONS_LIST="${HOME}/deploy/deployments/exclusions/exclusions.txt"
ssh -v "$USER1@$SVR_WEB1_WEBSERVER"
/usr/bin/rsync -avzh --progress --delete -e ssh --group=$GROUP1 -p --exclude-from "$EXCLUSIONS_LIST" "$FROM_DIR" "$USER1@$SVR_WEB1_WEBSERVER:$DEST1"
```

Comment: I followed instructions found somewhere in gitlab with no success either https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/2386

Answer (score 1):

Providing your private ssh key is dangerous unless you use your own gitlab-ci runners for deployment. That's why it is better to use [rsync modules](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsyncd.conf.html).

Comment: I'm **not** providing my private SSH key to anyone or any service (e.g. Gitlab). Please understand that this is not a private server running Gitlab/Gitlab CI, it is their Gitlab servers that I using to deploy from. Hope that helps to clear some things up. If you have experience rsync'ing files from their Gtilab-CI service to a private server, please provide a sample. Thank you.

Comment: My apologies. I misread what kind of key you want use. And I have newer used official gitlab/ci to host/build projects. Anyway, I believe, every time you did commit runner creates a fresh instance which has not either a private or public key. In your gitlab.yml you have to create them with ssh-keygen command. But then you will find a problem with upload  public key to your server.
Please check the link I provided before, it has some usefull examples on how to run rsync in daemon mode. 
There is a quick [how-to](http://transamrit.net/docs/rsync/) as well. 
It will help you to get rid of keys.